# Слово "щепетильность"

Tags: этимология

Хотелось бы узнать этимологию слова "щепетильность", а то даже вариантов нет, как оно появилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этимология слова "щепетильный" (наряжаться, модничать, щеголять и т.д.) не вполне объясняет современное значение слова - "строго, до мелочей последовательный и принципиальный в отношениях с кем-нибудь или по отношению к чему-нибудь" (Ожегов). Мне кажется интересной интерпретация этого слова авторами этимологического словаря Шанской, Иванова и Шанского, которые пишут, что первоначальное зачение слова "щепетильный" - "очень следящий за своей одеждой".

Answer (score 2):

Да в общем-то слово известное, вполне "прозрачное".

Происходит от щепети́ть «наряжаться, модничать», щепети́льник «галантерейщик, мелочной торговец», щепети́льный; диал. ще́петкой «плотный, крепкий, прочный», арханг., щепетли́вый «щегольской», щепети́нье «галантерейные товары». Первонач., по-видимому, ще́пет «галантерея» от щепа́ в знач. «мелочь».
(Вики словарь)

Comment: Ну, не очень прозрачное. Это все слова одного круга.  
А вот есть слово "щепоть", "щепотка" - они связаны с заявленным смыслом?

Comment: Не понял как "один круг" и "прозрачность" связвны. Прозрачное=светлое - антоним темному, с неясной этимологией.     
Щепоть и щепотка, думаю, связаны. Они же очевидным образом восходят к "щепе", мелкой части чего-то.

Comment: Один круг? Как сепульки у Лема: то, что применяется для сепулькирования. 
Я имела в виду, связаны ли щепоть и щепетильность.

Comment: Да. Именно на этото вопрос я вам и ответил. Или понимаете под "связаны" нечто иное, не этимологическую родственность?!

Comment: Мне непонятно, как именно перейти от "щепоти" к "щепетильности" через галантерею.  

А впрочем, с моей стороны это праздное любопытство.

Comment: Ну смотря что понимать под "перейти". Примерно как от дяди к племяннику:
щепоть<щепа
щепетильный<щепет(галантерея)<щепа.
Общий морф - щепа = мелочь, кусочек чего. Щепет (галантерея) = всякая мелочь.
Остальное, вроде, совсем уж не нуждается в комментариях.